# convert a select into an update

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am working with SQLite, I have created the following select statement which gives me the results I need, now how to get them where I need them:

```
SELECT 
  ii.Invoice_Item_Id,
  pli.PRICE,
  (pli.PRICE * ii.Qty) AS Sub_Total
FROM
  Invoice_Item ii
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CS_PRICE_LIST_ITEM pli ON (ii.Product_Id = pli.Product_Id)
  AND (pli.EVENT_PRICE_LIST_ID = 2)
WHERE
  ii.Invoice_Id = ?
```

The Invoice_Item table has two columns: ii.Price, ii.Sub_Total.  Both are NULL.  The goal is to set them to the result of this query, where  ii.Price = pli.PRICE and ii.Sub_Total = (pli.PRICE * ii.Qty).  Of course, I don't want to update the whole table, just for the given ii.Invoice_Id.  I know there is a really useful way of doing inserts from a select, is there a way to do that with updates?  If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

The `update` statement in SQLite does not support `join`s.  However, you can often update things using a correlated subquery.  The following may be what you are looking for:

```
update InvoiceItem
    set Sub_Total = (select coalesce(ii.Sub_Total, coalesce(ii.Price, pli.PRICE) * ii.Qty) 
                     FROM Invoice_Item ii LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          CS_PRICE_LIST_ITEM pli
                          ON ii.Product_Id = pli.Product_Id and
                             pli.EVENT_PRICE_LIST_ID = 2
                     WHERE ii.Invoice_Id = InvoiceItem.Invoice_Id
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did a poor job asking the question.  I just went back and edited my question to be more accurate.  If you would be so kind as to have another look, I would greatly appreciate it!